# CURL: BAD REQUEST error when trying to call http url

Tags: php, curl, web

I am trying to call an sms api using a http url .I am trying to call the url using curl in php.I get a BAD REQUEST error .Please explain what I am doing wrong.

```
// create a new cURL resource
    $ch = curl_init();
    $string1 = "http://api.znisms.com/post/smsv3.asp?userid=alpesh67&apikey=74c6314840a16c5e7db00415a03181f7&message= Congratulation you have been successfully registered in the Placement Management System \n Email:".$email."\n Password:".$password."&senderid=PMS12345&sendto=".$contactno."";
    echo $string1;
    // set URL and other appropriate options
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $string1);
    // grab URL and pass it to the browser
    curl_exec($ch);
    //close cURL resource, and free up system resources
    curl_close($ch);
    //SMS END
```

I get the following error:

```
http://api.znisms.com/post/smsv3.asp?userid=alpesh67&apikey=74c6314840a16c5e7db00415a03181f7&message= Congratulation you have been successfully registered in the Placement Management System Email:alpeshhi@gmail.com Password:123456789&senderid=PMS12345&sendto=9773396773
Bad Request
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can't use spaces in a URL. You need to url encode this string:

```
&message= Congratulation you have been successfully registered in the Placement Management System \n Email:".$email."\n Password:".$password."
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

> Returns a string in which all non-alphanumeric characters except -_.
>   have been replaced with a percent (%) sign followed by two hex digits
>   and spaces encoded as plus (+) signs. It is encoded the same way that
>   the posted data from a WWW form is encoded, that is the same way as in
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded media type. This differs from the »
>   RFC 3986 encoding (see rawurlencode()) in that for historical reasons,
>   spaces are encoded as plus (+) signs.

I would do something to the effect of:

```
// create a new cURL resource
    $ch = curl_init();
    $encoded_message = urlencode( "Congratulation you have been successfully registered in the Placement Management System \n Email:".$email."\n Password:".$password)
    $string1 = "http://api.znisms.com/post/smsv3.asp?userid=alpesh67&apikey=74c6314840a16c5e7db00415a03181f7&message=".$encoded_message."&senderid=PMS12345&sendto=".$contactno."";
    echo $string1;
    // set URL and other appropriate options
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $string1);
    // grab URL and pass it to the browser
    curl_exec($ch);
    //close cURL resource, and free up system resources
    curl_close($ch);
    //SMS END
```

Comment: I did try to just call the url created from the web browser and it works.So the spaces in the message are not the problem. But i still tried your solution and i still get the error.

Comment: Do you have an updated error? The contents of the URL in the error should be different with the urlencode() added.

Comment: I have the same error, but there aren't any spaces in the passed url. And when I try to access the url directly, it runs. :/

Answer (score 1):

It may be due to the message being passed with spaces in the url.
Try to urlencod

Answer (score 1):

Use urlencode() on the url as there are spaces. Also it is good practice to include a curl heaader as follows:

```
$headers = array("User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.0.8) Gecko/20061025 Firefox/1.5.0.8");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
```

Answer (score 1):

**THIS CODE FOR SEND Message after registration Completed. 
I think its helpful for you**

```
$Res = mysqli_query($conn, $str);
if ($Res) 
{
    $last_Id=mysqli_insert_id($conn);
    $message="Registration Successful your Reg.Id is $last_Id You Get Confirmation Message if your Registration Accepeted.";
    $contact=$_POST['contact'];      
    $url = "http://api.znisms.com/post/smsv3.asp?userid=Test1234&apikey=74c6714840a16c5e7db00815a03181f7&message=".urlencode($message)."&senderid=KKK1278&sendto=".urlencode($contact)."";

    // create a new cURL resource
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    // Process your response here
    echo $response;
    //header('location:../stdRegistration.php');
}
```

Comment: Could you add explanation why this code would be helpful? How is it different than other answers here suggesting using `urlencode`?